# How to See Windows Phone 8.1 SQLite PCL Database Physically

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a Windows Phone 8.1 App which contain SQLIte Database. Database is working perfectly and I am able to successfully store and retrieve data. I am running this app using Windows Phone emulator.

Now I want to see Database physically using some tool on computer.

Can Any please tell me the required steps to see it physically?

Comment: I think there is no need to specify question as unclear as it has already been answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to

1) dump the content of the installed application (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286408(v=vs.105).aspx)

2) use some tool on the computer to do whatever you need with the DB (many tools available, such as http://sqlitebrowser.org/)